# Does SoftLayer support to create image from compressed image file in Swift obejct storage

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I just created the image from VHD file in Swift object storage. Does SoftLayer support to import the compressed image file. Because the upload time is too long to wait.

Thank you. :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you should be able to import VHD files from a SWIF object storage, just go to https://control.softlayer.com/devices/images and click over **Import Image**

> Images imported from an Object Storage account may be either VHDs or
>   custom ISOs. VHD imports are restricted to the following 64-bit
>   operating systems:
>
> - CentOS 6 and 7
> - RedHat Enterprise Linux 6 and 7
> - Ubuntu 14.04, and 16.04
> - Microsoft Server Standard 2012, R2 2012, and 2016
>
> VHD imports are limited to 100GB disks. VHDs should be named as follows:
>   filename.vhd-0.vhd

Reference:

https://knowledgelayer.softlayer.com/procedure/import-image

Comment: And it support vhd image tarball?

Comment: I'm not sure, check https://knowledgelayer.softlayer.com/procedure/import-image and https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/QEMU/Images#Converting_image_formats . If there isn't any related to "vhd image tarball" then it may not be supported.  The image should have the extension *.vhd and the file name format should be something like this:  filename.vhd-0.vhd

Comment: Thank you. I just decompress the tarball in my code though it was not good for network transmission.